# Getting Error With Google Maps Places API with lookUpPlaceID

Tags: swift3, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to run the below code :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapPOIWithPlaceID placeID: String, name: String, location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("You tapped \(name): \(placeID), \(location.latitude)/\(location.longitude)")

        infoMarker.snippet = placeID
        infoMarker.position = location
        infoMarker.title = name
        infoMarker.opacity = 0;
        infoMarker.infoWindowAnchor.y = 1
        infoMarker.map = mapView
        mapView.selectedMarker = infoMarker

        placesClient!.lookUpPlaceID(placeID, callback: { (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            if let place = place {
                print("Place name \(place.name)")
                print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
                print("Place placeID \(place.placeID)")
                print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
            } else {
                print("No place details for \(placeID)")
            }
        } as! GMSPlaceResultCallback)
    }
```

As soon as the lookUpPlaceID line runs, it throws the exception :

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(placeId, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in
  if let error = error {
    print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return
  }

  if let place = place {
    print("Place name \(place.name)")
    print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
    print("Place placeID \(place.placeID)")
    print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
  } else {
    print("No place details for \(placeID)")
 }
})
```

Comment: That worked, could you explain what I was doing wrong?